# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token Nodejs

Tags: node.js, linkagem

Não consigo linkar corretamente meus arquivos de static/index, segue o código

diretório: 'blog/createServer.js'

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var contentTypes = {
  'html': 'text/html',
  'css': 'text/css',
  'ico': 'image/x-icon',
  'png': 'image/png',
  'svg': 'image/svg+xml',
  'js': 'application/javascript',
  'otf': 'application/x-font-otf',
  'ttf': 'application/x-font-ttf',
  'eot': 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject',
  'woff': 'application/x-font-woff',
  'woff2': 'application/font-woff2',
  'zip': 'application/zip'
}

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  //A constante __dirname retorna o diretório raiz da aplicação.
  fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'static', 'index.html'), function(err, html) {
    response.writeHeader(200, {
      'Context-Type': contentTypes['html', 'css', 'js']
    });
    response.write(html);
    response.end();
  })
})

server.listen(8000, function() {
  console.log("Executanto Site pessoal");
})
```

diretório: 'blog/static/index.html'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>



    <script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

obs... os arquivos que quero linkar estão em 'blog/static/libs/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás a responder a pedidos de ficheiros `.css` e `.js`  com o conteúdo de `index.html`, daí estares a receber erros de caracteres `<` dentro de CSS e JS.

Tens de ler o `request.url` para saber o que foi pedido e depois agir conforme isso. Um exemplo seria como escrevi em baixo. Num proximo passo seria melhor ter esses ficheiros em cache, se não tiveres NginX ou outro servidor http que faça isso.

Testa o exemplo em baixo e confirma que compreendes a lógica.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var contentTypes = {
    'html' : 'text/html',
    'css'  : 'text/css',
    'ico'  : 'image/x-icon',
    'png'  : 'image/png',
    'svg'  : 'image/svg+xml',
    'js'   : 'application/javascript',
    'otf'  : 'application/x-font-otf',
    'ttf'  : 'application/x-font-ttf',
    'eot'  : 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject',
    'woff' : 'application/x-font-woff',
    'woff2': 'application/font-woff2',
    'zip'  : 'application/zip'
};

var server = http.createServer(function(request,response){
    var ext = request.url.split('.').pop();
    if (contentTypes[ext]){
        var filename = request.url.split('/').pop();
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'static', filename), function(err, str){
            response.writeHeader(200, {'Context-Type': contentTypes[ext]});
            response.write(str);
            response.end();
        });
    } else {
        // aqui deves servir os outros ficheiros
        // deixo aqui somente o `index.html`
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'), function(err, html){
            response.writeHeader(200, {'Context-Type': contentTypes.html});
            response.write(html);
            response.end();
        });
    }
});
server.listen(8000, function(){
    console.log("Executanto Site pessoal");
});
```